# Concentrate dataset arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Hi I have many arrays of different lengths now I want to create ONE long array (1D) out of all of them. Counterintuitively vertcat gives me a dimension error even though I do not see the point why the dimensions of my arrays should match.

Am I using vertcat wrong?

Comment: How do you use it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vectors are probably column vectors of different lengths (or matrices). Suppose `A` to `D` are the matrices you want to create a 1D-vector from. Try "flattening" them out using `(:)`, and vertcat thereafter, like this:

```
long_1D_vector = [A(:); B(:); C(:); D(:)];
```

You may transpose it if you want a column vector instead:

```
long_1D_vector = [A(:); B(:); C(:); D(:)].';
```

Comment: this does it. Thank you